# SEP Date control - DateChange event does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA to work with SEP Date control (using Office 2016). Normally it seems to work fine, but when I add any code in DateChanged() procedure the date is not changing.
I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub LDDate1_DateChanged()
    Debug.Print Me.LDDate1.Date
End Sub
```

E.g: Current date on callendar is 2017/12/14. When I click Calendar and choose (mouse click) 2017/12/15, it returns 2017-12-14 (twice!) in Immediate window . Calendar is also still 2017/12/14. Calendar works fine when I delete

```
Debug.Print Me.LDDate1.Date
```

I'd really appretiate any support on these